# Creating inter-terminal applications for Linux systems

Tags: linux, debian, terminal, bsd

On a Debian machine, I have the BSD games installed, but I wanted to know if it was possible for the monop game to be played with other users on the server. This type of inter-terminal play is a feature of a few other BSD games in the suite but not this one.

Is it possible to make monop inter-terminal? Or is there perhaps another Monopoly program somewhere else that has been created that does this already?